# Non-bluetooth tuner and speakers

Tags: bluetooth, converter

Is there a way to connect a non-Bluetooth receiver/turner (Yamaha) to non- Bluetooth speakers (Klipsch) using a blue-tooth converter in receive mode (speakers) and Bluetooth converter in transmit mode (tuner)?

Comment: I don't see why not. Just don't ask for a schematic or a product recommendation here.

Answer (score 0):

Line out to the Bluetooth transmitter. If it doesn't have line out, then you need an amplified output to line level converter. Then the line out of the Bluetooth receiver to an amplifier for the speakers, unless they have a built-in amplifier with line in.